# Adaptive sliding window to detect varying time periods in time series dataset

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am looking for an algorithm that will allow me to segment time series with varying time periods. I have attached an image to better represent my intentions -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Segment the data when the average over a fixed-length window of 5 or 10 points is minimal within +- 5 or 10 such aggregates?

What's wrong with such classic "local minimum" segmentation on this data set?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on 'local minimum segmentation'?

Comment: I already did in the sentence before...

Comment: Actually, I am a little new to these techniques. Can you suggest me where I can get more information for the same?